# Rendered Size of FrameworkElement (inside ViewBox) changed

Tags: wpf, bitmap, rendertransform

In WPF, is there a way to detect that the actual render size (measured in screen units) changed?

I have elements which contain a rendered bitmap. If these elements are placed inside a Viewbox (or some other control that deals with RenderTransforms), I want to render the bitmap in the actual size on screen, so that no interpolation is done.

The main idea is that I want to place some complex parts of the UI in bitmaps as these would otherwise (when drawed in retained mode) reduce the render framerate and UI responsivity, making the application a pain to use. As a side effect, I would like to draw the lines inside these controls with constant thickness, even if scaled.

One way would be to check the size on screen with every render pass (or in some given time interval), and if it changed redraw the bitmap. However, I would like to know if there is maybe a built-in way to achieve this.

Comment: yes. the FrameworkElement.SizeChanged event. This event will be triggered whenever the ActualWidth or ActualHeight is changed. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.sizechanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: No. The SizeChanged event is only invoked if the size of the control itself changes, but not when the size of the surrounding ViewBox (and thus the RenderTransform) changes.

Comment: ah my bad. I would have thought <Viewbox SizeChanged="Size_changed" ..> would work. good luck

Comment: You are right that I could manually notify the child if I put it in a Viewbox. The problem is that every ancestor FrameworkElement could use a RenderTransform, if it wants - not only Viewbox. I am looking for a "generic" way...